# How to read keyboard input and assign it to a local variable?

Tags: bash, variable, read, declare

I have this very simple script:

```
#!/bin/bash

read local _test
echo "_test: $_test"
```

This is the output.

```
$ ./jltest.sh
sdfsdfs
_test:
```

I want the variable `_test` to be local only. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The local builtin only works inside a function.  Any variable you set in your script will already be "local" to the script though unless you explicitly `export` it. So if you remove that it will work as expected:

```
#!/bin/bash

read _test
echo "_test: $_test"
```

Or you could make it a function:

```
my_read () {
  local _test
  read _test
  echo "_test: $_test"
}
```

Even inside the function the `local` builtin wouldn't work in the way you have written it:

---

Your code is actually setting a variable literally named `local`:

```
#!/bin/bash

read local _test
echo "_test: $_test"
echo "local: $local"
```

---

```
$ ./script.sh
sssss aaaaa
_test: aaaaa
local: sssss
```